# I keep getting an error with NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations

[image]

I keep getting an error that says equations expected instead of True in the first argument but I put equations so I don't know if i just formatted or typed it wrong or what

Comment: Please do not post images of your work. Please post your actual Mathematica code in the form of text that can be copied and pasted into a Mathematica notebook. Without such, people who wan to help you will have do a lot of work to reproduce your problem so they can experiment with possible solutions.

Comment: Looks like you executed your NDSolve above with a single equal sign on the last boundary condition, thereby setting y'[0] to 25.28. You then switched it to the correct double equal sign, and tried again, getting a True as the last boundary condition. Restart your kernel and try it again, and it should work.

Comment: Use `Sqrt` rather than `sqrt`